# Yii Framework - Routing is not working

Tags: php, yii, routes, yii2, yii-url-manager

Coming from laravel background. Currently developing web service using yii framework but routing is not working as expected.

This is the expected route to call web service. "api" is ApiController, "totalviews" is actionTotalviews.

```
  localhost/myproject/admin/api/totalviews
```

This is my web.php file in config directory.

```
`'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'homeUrl' => 'http://localhost/myproject/admin/', 
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'defaultRoute' => 'login/index',
    'components' => [
        'twiliosms' => [
            'class' => 'app\components\TwilioSms',
        ],
        'request' => [
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'abc123',
            'parsers' => [
                'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
            ]
        ],
        'urlManager' =>
            [
                'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
                'showScriptName' => false,
                'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
                'rules' => [
                    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                    '<view:(about)>' => 'login/page',
                    '<action:(index)>' => 'login/<action>',
                    '<action:(forgotpassword)>' => 'login/forgotpassword<action>',
                    '<alias:dashboard|forgotpassword>' => 'login/<alias>',
                ],
            ]
```

The is htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

This is admin/index.php.

```
require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

$config = require(__DIR__ . '/../config/web.php');

(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();`
```

The default route will direct to login controller and actionIndex. But I tried the below to expected route but 404 not found.

```
   -localhost/myproject/admin/api/totalviews
   -localhost/myproject/admin/index.php?r=api/totalviews
   -localhost/myproject/index.php?r=api/totalviews
```

Appreciate your assistance!

Comment: where is your entry script (index.php) in your project? if you are using the default yii2 basic template or advanced template, the entry script should be inside the web directory inside your application.

Comment: @marche Hi, I edited the question and put in index.php.

Comment: wich yii2 you use? yii2advanced or yii2basic?

Comment: It is yii2 basic. @ali

Comment: why you use admin in your rout? Are you test without admin?

Comment: [JohnnyCc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5336658/johnnycc), have you found solution. I am having same problem with no clues. Please help.